# Call a specific scenario using tag, before another scenario?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

How can be translated into (java script nodejs) cucumber hooks the following statement:

**Call @tag1 before @tag2**?

When I run @tag2 automatically the @tag1 is called before @tag2.

```
@tag1 
Scenario: populate cars
...

@tag2 
Scenario: sell car
...
```

this command I want to use: /node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js --tags "@tag2"

In this case  "Before" hooks should stimulate the tag tag1 to run before tag2.

How to write Before hook in this case?

```
 Before('@tag2', function () {
...
}
```

### Second question

Is it possible to compose a tag from a tag expression?

Eq. @tag3 = @tag1 and @tag2

When run the commands is called just the tag3:
/node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js --tags "@tag3"

Answer (score 1):

There might be a technical solution to your problem, but really there is a philosophical solution, which also serves as a technical solution.

Cucumber scenarios should be independent. Each scenario should be a complete test when executed on its own. It makes sense that you need to "populate cars" before selling them. Instead of calling the "populate cars" scenario from the "selling cars" scenario, you should create new `Given` steps that simulate the behavior described in the "populate cars" scenario.

Since you haven't provided the steps for each scenario, I can only guess what they might be. The scenario about selling cars would probably look something like:

```
Scenario: sell car
    Given a 1972 "Ford" "Pinto" is in stock # <-- this simulates the "populate cars" step
    When ...
    Then ...
```

An alternative if your scenario requires more than one car is to use a data table:

```
Scenario: sell car
    Given the following cars are in stock: # <-- this simulates the "populate cars scenario
        | Year | Make | Model | Price |
        | 1972 | Ford | Pinto | ...   |
        | 2020 | BMW  | M3    | ...   |
    When ...
    Then ...
```

The implementation of the `Given` step is up to you. This step can navigate the real user interface or make web service calls to populate the cars. This is up to you, and depends on what APIs you have available to your cucumber step definitions.

Comment: Thank you for  your opinion. But, for me is important if it is possible to call a scenario inside the hooks and how to do. The scenarios mentioned above are just example.

Answer (score 0):

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#running-a-subset-of-scenarios

Switch language to JS and you have all the help you need.

For this instance you would want something like

./node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js --tags "@tag1 and @tag2"

Comment: in the command I want to run the just the tag "@tag2" ("/node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js --tags "@tag2"). In this case using hooks "Before" stimulate before tag2 to run tag1.  I don't know how to write in Before hooks.

Comment: I've given you the solution for how to run a scenario based on tags? If you need something else then you need to amend your OP?

As for your 2nd question. You can do this, but you wouldn't save the result as a tag. You've just call it as you mentioned. Run using "@tag1 and @tag2"